# Curl of $\frac{\hat r}{r^2}$ using two different coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, vector-fields

I am learning vector calculus. Here I wanted to take out the $\nabla\times(\frac{\hat r}{r^2})$ ,
So in spherical coordinates it is easy to take out. It is zero.
but while doing in Cartesian coordinates
$\begin{bmatrix}
 \hat x & \hat y & \hat z \\
 \frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\\
 \frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)} & \frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)} & \frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)} \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$

This on solving isn't coming to be zero. Why?

Comment: It's because you're taking the curl of the wrong vector field. $$\frac{\hat{r}}{r^2} = \frac{(x,y,z)}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^\frac{3}{2}} \neq \frac{(1,1,1)}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$

Comment: Oh thanks, What a silly mistake!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

$\frac{\hat{r}}{r^2} = \frac{(x,y,z)}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^\frac{3}{2}} \neq \frac{(1,1,1)}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$

Thanks to Ninad Munshi.